# Use agrep to return a different variable

Tags: r, agrep

I'm doing a lookup from one table to another using agrep, but the results I want to return are not the values being matched.  They're from another column/variable.  My current agrep syntax:

```
personalfolders$DOBMatch <- lapply(personalfolders$DOB, agrep, allees2$`Date Of Birth`, max.distance=1)
```

So now: `personalfolders$DOBMatch == c(290, 312)` but what I want is to return the values from another variable in the data frame I'm looking up called: `allees2$PartPathmatch1` for each of those returned rows.  I know about the value=TRUE variable for agrep, but I believe that only returns the lookup value itself.

Is there a way I can either use the `personalfolders$DOBMatch` field that now contains something like `c(290, 312)` to create another vector then add it to the frame with the lookup results, or can I add another argument to the agrep function to return the `allees2$PartpathMatch1` matched values directly?

Comment: `allees2$PartPathmatch1[c(290,312)]`

Comment: @Jaap That would mean I would be doing:    `personalfolders$DOBMatch1 <- allees2$PartPathMatch1[personalfolders$DOBMatch]` but that doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
personalfolders$DOBMatch <- lapply(personalfolders$DOB, function(y) allees2$PartPathMatch1[agrep(y, allees2$`Date Of Birth`, max.distance=1)])
```